# How to pass data to multiple notification and clear when click on it

Tags: android

Android

passing multiple data to notification
when i click on notification its only open recent one

```
final Notification notifyDetails = new Notification(R.drawable.e4,"temp",System.currentTimeMillis());
                    long[] vibrate = {100,100,200,300};
                    notifyDetails.vibrate = vibrate;
                    notifyDetails.defaults =Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    CharSequence contentTitle = "hello"
                    CharSequence contentText = "You have a notification" ;
                    Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(context, Send_Notification_Act.class);
                    notifyIntent.putExtra("name", "sunil");
                    notifyIntent.putExtra("ID", SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID);
                    PendingIntent intent =
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(Back_Reciver.this, 0,
                    notifyIntent, android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    notifyDetails.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, intent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
private int SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID = 0;
private int SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID_A = 1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Button quick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.quickbutton);        

    quick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            displayNotification("Text", "Text", "Text", MyActivity.class,       SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID);

            displayNotification("Text", "Text", "Text", MyActivityA.class, SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID_A);
        }
    });
}

private void displayNotification(String extra, String contentTitle, String   contentText, Class<?> cls, int id) {     
    Notification notifyDetails = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "New Alert!",   System.currentTimeMillis());
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, cls);
    intent.putExtra("extra", extra);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    notifyDetails.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(id, notifyDetails);
}
```